# Timer with restart

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to create a simple timer where it displays the current remaining time (in my code, I am using turtle to make it cleaner, but just printing one less second every second would work just fine as well). The catch is that I want it so that if I hit a key on my keyboard (it can be a specific key, like enter, or space), I want the timer to restart. Here is my current code

```
time = input("Please enter the time").strip()
time = time.split(" ")
for i in range(len(time)):
    time[i]=int(time[i])
print(time)
seconds = 3600*time[0]+60*time[1]+time[2]
import turtle as turt
from time import sleep
t = turt.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
    t.clear()
    t.write(i, align = 'center', font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
    sleep(1)
t.clear()
t.write("TIMER DONE", align = 'center', font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
```

How can I make it so that when I click a key on my keyboard the timer restarts. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**EDIT:** Basically, what I want is a way to make it so whenever I press a key on my keyboard, it doesn't matter which key, it restarts the program regardless of which line the program is currently on.

Comment: Put code into a loop.

Comment: How would that help? Currently I am using sleep...which, in essence, "stops" the program for 1 second. so if I press enter or whatever, it would have to be at the exact moment when the program is running and not in the `sleep(1)` command. Also, how would I make it so that whenever I press the key, despite which line the program is currently on, it would restart the timer.

Comment: Basically, what I want is a way to make it so whenever I press a key on my keyboard, it doesn't matter which key, it restarts the program regardless of which line the program is currently on.

Comment: How would you implement a pause as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would toss time/sleep and use turtle's own `ontimer()` to do the countdown.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ("Arial", 40, "normal")

strings = input("Please enter the time: ").strip().split(' ')

time = [60 ** (len(strings) - index - 1) * int(unit) for index, unit in enumerate(strings)]

seconds = -1
ticking = False

def tick():
    global seconds, ticking

    turtle.clear()

    if seconds < 0:
        turtle.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=FONT)
        ticking = False
    else:
        turtle.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)
        seconds -= 1
        screen.ontimer(tick, 1000)

def reset():
    global seconds, ticking

    screen.onkey(None, "Return")  # Disable event handler inside handler

    seconds = sum(time)

    if not ticking:
        ticking = True
        tick()

    screen.onkey(reset, "Return")  # Reenable event handler

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

reset()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

When you hit , it will go back to the orignal value and start counting down again.  Even after the timer stops.  If you just want 15 seconds on the clock, just enter "15", you don't need to enter *all* the fields.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! I have just one question. Would it be possible to make it so wherever I click on the keyboard it works (not including the function key row, or alt, ctrl, Fn, CapsLock, etc.) without hardcoding each one into the code?

Comment: @BobRobert, yes, provided you don't care *which* key was pressed.  If so, replace `screen.onkey(reset, "Return")` with `screen.onkeypress(reset)`  and replace `screen.onkey(None, "Return")` with `screen.onkeypress(None)`.  (Note that both the method name and arguments have changed.)  This should do it.  If you care which key, the issue gets more complicated.

Comment: Ok, one more thing, if I made it for a specific key that would restart the timer. How would I make it that for a different key it would pause the timer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, timer will reset when you press space.

```
time = input("Please enter the time").strip()
        time = time.split(" ")
        for i in range(len(time)):
            time[i] = int(time[i])
        print(time)
        seconds = 3600 * time[0] + 60 * time[1] + time[2]
        print(seconds)
        import turtle as turt
        from time import sleep
        wn = turt.Screen()
        t = turt.Turtle()
        turt.listen()

        def reset(seconds):
            t.hideturtle()
            turt.listen()
            turt.onkey(up, "space")
            for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
                t.clear()
                t.write(i, align='center', font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
                sleep(1)
            t.clear()
            t.write("TIMER DONE", align='center', font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))


        def up():
            t.clear()
            seconds = 3600 * time[0] + 60 * time[1] + time[2]
            reset(seconds)

        reset(seconds)
        turt.done()
```

Comment: This doesn't *reset* the timer, it starts a *new* timer!  Start it running with 10 seconds on the clock and hit the space bar four times.  Then let it count all the way down and watch the fun begin.  (It also doesn't run as posted.)

Comment: why did you make all the lines after the first line double indented?